# Formula references data that are not shown

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help with my Google Sheets... I don't understand why but my data are capricious...

I use a simple `={'Mysheet'!A1:D}` and I get only the first cell.

Please find a link to a copy of my sheet. The problem is in 'Up&Down OR'

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJ_bqQtsjWe9RxaDzLUypY-D9dyuqWNpw2pG0XHVYjI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

most likely there is some residue from the script you are usiing but you can always reference original:

```
=QUERY(Encodage!A1:AAA ;"select C, " & params!K1 & ", " & params!L1 & ", " & params!M1 & " where A = FALSE AND B = '1OR' ORDER BY " & params!K1 & " + " & params!L1 & " + " & params!M1 & " LIMIT 10 LABEL " & params!K1 & " '" & INDIRECT("Encodage!"& params!K1 & "1") & "', " & params!L1 & " '" & INDIRECT("Encodage!"& params!L1 & "1") & "', " & params!M1 & " '" & INDIRECT("Encodage!"& params!M1 & "1") & "'" ;1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I tried that before but I remember the next formula using these datas didn't work... see on F1, same Sheet

Comment: your formula in F1 has bad syntax

Comment: Bad syntax ? I simplified it and you can check yourself. There is still a problem :-(

Comment: could you please explain how my formula has bad syntax ? thanks

Comment: formula you had in F1 was, now it looks ok. anyway is this still not solved?